# Inject the right implementation according to configuration parameter with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I am using Springboot and so Spring dependency Injection Framework. I would like to know if it is possible to inject a specific implementation of an interface, depending on the value of a configuration parameter

Let's say I have an interface `MyInterface` and two implementations `MyImplementation1` and `MyImplementation2`

```
interface MyInterface {
  ...
}


@Component
public class MyImplementation1 implements MyInterface {
  ...
}


@Component
public class MyImplementation2 implements MyInterface {
  ...
}
```

and I have a configuration class `MyConfiguration`

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("my.configuration")
public class MyConfiguration {

    protected boolean myBoolean;
 
    ...    
}
```

Now I want to inject `MyImplementation1` into class `MyClass` if `myBoolean == true` and `MyImplementation2` if `myBoolean == false`

```
@Component
class MyClass {

  @Autowired
  public MyClass(MyInterface myInterface) {
    ...
  }
 
  ...
}
```

How should I do?

Thanks for help

Comment: Do you expect the other bean also to be created when the flag is true/false? In other words, would you be needing both beans during your application runtime?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@ConditionalOnProperty` to create a bean when certain property is set to an expected value.

```
interface MyInterface {
...
}


@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(value="my.configuration.my-boolean", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
public class MyImplementation1 implements MyInterface {
  ...
}


@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(value="my.configuration.my-boolean", havingValue = "false")
public class MyImplementation2 implements MyInterface {
  ...
}
```